# Google custom search API and Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-api

I wanted to write a Google search scraper/parser to pull employees from Google's index of linkedin.com. Linkedin closed their API, so I wrote a Mechanize/Nokogiri scraper first, which got me captcha'd, so I rewrote the script using the Google search API gem.

The problem is, I can't figure out where to begin to make it bring back more than the first page of results and the official docs couldn't even be described as 'sparse'.

This is the code that returns page 1 only:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'google/api_client'
require 'json'
require 'pp'
puts "What organisation's employees shall we get today?"
organisation = gets.chomp
puts "Harvesting Google Search Results - This may take some time"

apikey = "1234"
cxid = "5678"
client = Google::APIClient.new(:key => apikey, :authorization => nil,          :application_name => "linkedout", :application_version => "beta_0.5")
  search = client.discovered_api('customsearch')
  response = client.execute(
 :api_method => search.cse.list,
 :parameters => {
   'q' => 'current ' + organisation + ' site:linkedin.com',
   'maxResults' => 100,
   'key' => apikey,
   'cx' => cxid
   }
)

status, headers, body = response
jsonresponse = response.body

employees = []
@tags = JSON.parse(jsonresponse)['items']
  @tags.each do |tag|
     x = tag['title']
     x.gsub!(/ \| LinkedIn/, "")
     x.downcase!
     x.gsub!(/ profiles/, "")
        employees << x
       end
    employees = employees.uniq
    puts employees
```

Any help would be very gratefully received - I'm still learning this stuff.

Edit:

Here is a snippet of the JSON google's API returns:

```
"items": [
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "Tina Minor - Recruiter, The Walt Disney Company | LinkedIn",
   "htmlTitle": "Tina Minor - Recruiter, The \u003cb\u003eWalt     Disney\u003c/b\u003e Company | LinkedIn",
   "link": "https://www.linkedin.com/pub/tina-minor-recruiter-the-walt-disney-    company/5/849/5a6",
   "displayLink": "www.linkedin.com",
   "snippet": "View Tina Minor - Recruiter, The Walt Disney Company's     professional profile on \n... Current. The Walt Disney Company. Previous. True     Religion Brand Jeans, ...",
   "htmlSnippet": "View Tina Minor - Recruiter, The \u003cb\u003eWalt     Disney\u003c/b\u003e Company&#39;s professional profile on \u003cbr\u003e\n...     \u003cb\u003eCurrent\u003c/b\u003e. The \u003cb\u003eWalt Disney\u003c/b\u003e     Company. Previous. True Religion Brand Jeans,&nbsp;...",
   "formattedUrl": "https://www.linkedin.com/pub/tina-minor-recruiter-the-    walt-   disney.../5a6",
       "htmlFormattedUrl": "https://www.linkedin.com/pub/tina-minor-recruiter-    the-       \u003cb\u003ewalt\u003c/b\u003e-    \u003cb\u003edisney\u003c/b\u003e.../5a6",
       "pagemap": {
        "cse_image": [
         {
           "src":          "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_200_200/p/8/005/09b/3f2/1eb6f83.jpg"
      }
    ],
    "person": [
     {
      "location": "Greater Los Angeles Area",
      "role": "Recruiter, Talent Acquisition at The Walt Disney Company"
     }
    ],
    "cse_thumbnail": [
     {
      "width": "160",
      "height": "160",
      "src": "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?    q=tbn:ANd9GcTbmlbDVBOMKTtOA_D88aFaPuZ9MjABABwumzBPk0F2x2P2-0puaIRlktce"
     }
    ],
    "metatags": [
     {
      "globaltrackingurl": "//www.linkedin.com/mob/tracking",
      "globaltrackingappname": "profile",
      "globaltrackingappid": "webTracking",
      "lnkd-track-json-lib": "https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?    h=2jds9coeh4w78ed9wblscv68v-ebbt2vixcc5qz0otts5io08xv&fc=2",
      "treeid": "SnQhTqcr1RNgnKS8RSsAAA==",
      "appname": "profile",
      "pageimpressionid": "29ca4803-0233-4934-955a-1959a37dfbbf",
      "pagekey": "nprofile_v2_public_fs",
      "analyticsurl": "/analytics/noauthtracker",
      "msapplication-tileimage":     "https://static.licdn.com/scds/common/u/images/logos/linkedin/logo-in-win8-tile-    144_v1.png",
      "msapplication-tilecolor": "#0077B5",
      "application-name": "LinkedIn",
      "remote-nav-init-marker": "true"
     }
    ],
    "hcard": [
     {
      "fn": "Tina Minor - Recruiter, The Walt Disney Company",
      "title": "Recruiter, Talent Acquisition at The Walt Disney Company"
     }
    ]
   }
  }
  ...
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you running? Any version from 1.9+ automatically requires RubyGems for you so `require 'rubygems'` is no longer needed.

Comment: Rather than expect us to gather sample JSON, it'd help if you showed a minimal example of input JSON to work with. Help us to help you.

Comment: Sorry Tin Man! You are absolutely correct. I left the JSON out because the JSON is already parsed, so I made the assumption (silly of me) that it wouldn't be relevant to pagination!

Comment: What do you mean you are getting only the first 'page' of results? JSON doesn't have pages. How many results are you getting?

Comment: It only returns the JSON for page1 of the Google search. Nothing more than that. It's the Google API that controls that as far as I can see. The number of results varies depending on the organisation you enter, but is typically 6-7 employees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Search request metadata](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest#search_request_metadata), there should be a `nextPage` value returned next to items when there are additional results. However it always says `Note: This API returns up to the first 100 results only.` so it looks like you are already getting the maximum number of results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!, I had missed that and assumed it was 100 results per page as with the standard browser :( Back to scraping with Mechanise it is!